# port code from XP to Win 7

Tags: delphi, namespaces

I have developed a Delphi application (XE4) on a Windows XP machine.
When I copy all the project files to a Win 7 machine (also Delphi XE4) it will not compile.

The source has `uses Vcl.Grids` and the compiler complains it can't find `vcl.grids.dcu`.
Changing to `uses grids` works but I don't want to edit all the source.
I've checked the Embarcadero website for information on Namespaces but couldn't find anything useful.
I know it's possible to say `uses vcl.grids` under Win 7 so there must be some setting somewhere in the project that is preventing the resolution.
I've tried deleting the dproj files but that had no effect.

How do I get the source to compile with minimal changes?

Comment: Why do you think this has someting to do with XP vs 7?

Comment: How is change the uses statements anything more than minimal changes? Do you not have a global search and replace in your project?

Comment: It seems more likely that you are compiling in XE or earlier.

Comment: What version of Delphi is installed on the new machine?  Is it possible that an older version of Delphi was installed on that machine?

Comment: Hi GrandmasterB - I don't think it has anything to do with the OS, I'm just trying to supply all relevant information.

Comment: It is the same version of XE on both maxhines.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the source code the same on both machines,

Comment: @Graham You need to make your mind up. Is it XE, or XE4? If it is XE then my answer applies.

Answer (score 2):

The error has nothing to do with OS.  It means your IDE/Projects's search paths are not configured correctly, or your project is missing references to the relevant packages, so double check that.

Also, you can use `uses Grids` in the code, and then make sure `Vcl` is listed in the **Unit scope names** field in the Project Options.

Comment: It can't be that. How would `Grids` be found, but not `Vcl.Grids`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: do you NOT know how Unit Scope names actually work? Especially in relation to the "Unit scope names" field in the Project Options? If the code say `uses Grids` and `Vcl` is listed in the Project Options, the compiler/linker will attempt to find a `Grids` or `Vcl.Grids` unit in referenced packages, and if not found then will attempt to find a `Grids.dcu` or `Vcl.Grids.dcu` file, and if not found then the compile will fail.

Comment: How would the compiler find Grids but not find Vcl.Grids?

Comment: My guess would be a package/library in the project or search path has its own `Grids` unit that is separate from the `Vcl.Grids` unit.

Comment: I think I do know how unit scope names work. By the way.

Answer (score 0):

The information that you describe seems to be erroneous. The compiler is not affected by the operating system on which it runs. Running the same compiler on the same source code on a different operating system does not result in compiler errors.

Here are the reasonable explanations for your problem:

- You are compiling the code on different versions of the compiler. Your error message matches what happens when you compile modern namespace aware code on XE or earlier.
- Your are not compiling the same source code on both machines.

It is extremely hard to see beyond these two explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, red face time. Turns out I was running an earlier version of Delphi on the Win 7 machine. Delphi XE4 was installed along with an earlier version and I was invoking the earlier version.
Once I actually brought up XE4 on the Win 7 machine the issue vanished.
So I will don a hair shirt and crawl under my rock.
Thanks everyone who contributed.